# Init static variable in synchronized block for all the threads, read without synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading

I often see the following pattern. One thread will initialize the client in init() method in synchronized block. All the other threads, also called init() method before they start to use the other class methods.
Client value is not changed after initialization. They dont set the client value as volatile.

My question is that if this is correct to do? Do all of the threads that create client, and call init() method , will after init method finished see the correct initilized value that was initialized byt the first thread that called init() method?

```
public class DB {

  private static Object lock = new Object();
  private static Client client;

  public init() {

    synchronized (lock) {
      if (client != null) {
        return;
      }
      client = new Client();
    }
  }

  public insert(Object data) {
    client.insert(data); // is this ok to access the client without volatile or synchronized?
  }
}
```

The rationale behind that pattern is that they think that because they read the client under synchronized block in init() method, the client will be set to the correct initialized value, and because the client is never changed, they can use it without volatile or synchronized after. IS this correct assumption?

You can see this pattern for example here: https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/cd1589ce6f5abf96e17aa8ab80c78a4348fdf29a/mongodb/src/main/java/site/ycsb/db/MongoDbClient.java where they initialized the database in init method and used it without synchronization after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only safe to do this if you are guaranteed to have called `init()` before calling `insert(data)`.

There is a happens-before edge created by the `synchronized` block: the end of the synchronized block happens before the next invocation of the same block.

This means that if a thread has invoked `init()`, then either:

- `client` was previously uninitialized, so it is initialized on this call.
- `client` was previously initialized, and the write to `client` is has happened before the current thread enters the `synchronized` block.

No further synchronization is then necessary, at least with respect to `client`.

However, if a thread *doesn't* call `init()`, then there are no guarantees as to whether `client` is initialized; and no guarantee as to whether the `client` initialized by another thread (one that did call `init()`) will be visible to the current thread (the one that didn't call `init()`).

Relying on clients to call `init()` first is brittle. It would be much better either to use an eagerly-initialized field:

```
public class DB {

  private static final Client client = new Client();

  public insert(Object data) {
    client.insert(data);  // Guaranteed to be initialized once class loading is complete.
  }
}
```

or, if you must do it lazily, use a lazy holder:

```
public class DB {
  private static class Holder {
    private static final Client client = new Client();
  }

  public insert(Object data) {
    Holder.client.insert(data);  // Holder.client is initialized on first access.
  }
}
```

Or, of course, chuck in a call to `init()` inside the `insert` method:

```
  public insert(Object data) {
    init();
    client.insert(data);
  }
```

The disadvantage of the latter approach is that all threads must synchronize. In the other two approaches, there is no contention after the first invocation.

Comment: Yes, I use the lazy holder in my code. I am only curios because i saw this pattern many times and I have never been sure if its correct. The main quesiton is if I read the variable in synchronized block, can I then use it later without synchronized or volatile. (preconditions are: that the value is not changed/updated anywher in code except init). From your answer, I see that its safe. I am not planning to use this pattern because its confusing, but I will know that its ok if I see it in other code that its not under my control.

Comment: As I say: it is safe provided all threads have invoked `init()`. In that case, no further synchronization is needed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the rationale behind this type of pattern is to ensure that you can only have one instance of `Client` in the application. Multiple invocations (parallel/sequential) of `init()` method on different/same DB objects will not allow creating a new Client if it is already created and `synchronized block` is just to ensure that client object will be created only once if `multiple threads` called `init()` parallelly.

But it has nothing to do with safe call of `insert()` method on client object and that totally depends on the implementation of the insert() method that may be thread-safe or may not be.

Comment: The question is different. Its about thread visibility. Can other threads use the lcient without volatile or synchronized?

Comment: @HPCS Without synchronized/volatile JVM does not guarantee that every update will be visible to other threads.

Comment: @HPCS short answer is: no, they can not. if you want to ensure guaranteed visibility, you should make client volatile

Comment: As I write in the quesiton, the preconditions is that the client is not changed/updated after init.

Comment: Yes to ensure your precondition you have to put it in synchronized block else multiple threads calling init() may end creating new object of the client and override the reference in client variable.

Comment: @AmitBera no only the first thread that call init will update the client, the block is synchronized under static lock, if the client is already initialized then it will not initialized it again.

Comment: @HPCS I am saying the same thing and synchronized is required for the same reason you have commented. You may optimized the like by null check before taking lock on the static object.